# How to remove (delete) annotation in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a different way than `kubectl edit` to delete an annotation in Kubernetes?

I do not like the interactivity of `kubectl edit`. I prefer something usable in a script.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use minus `-` sign at the end of the annotation in `kubectl annotate`.

Example:

`kubectl annotate service shopping-cart prometheus.io/scrape-`

Removes annotation `prometheus.io/scrape` from `shopping-cart` service.

Comment: also works same way for istio virtual services 
`kubectl annotate vs -n NAMESPACE VSERVICE kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration-`

Answer (score 8):

An alternative way to achieve this goal, might be using `kubectl patch` command by invoking JSON patch method. Unfortunately it is more weighty solution comparing to your answer:

`kubectl patch svc <Service_name>  --type=json -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/metadata/annotations/prometheus.io~1scrape"}]'`

More detailed information can be found in [Jsonpatch](http://jsonpatch.com) document.

Comment: a regular `kubectl patch` setting the value of the annotation to `null` also works