# What is the API equivalent for adding/deleting kubernetes annotations?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-python-client

I'm trying to find the API equivalent of [How to remove (delete) annotation in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54973593/5291015)
 to remove annotation for a service type in Python. Doing it from the command line works perfectly fine.

The latest [kubernetes-client/python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/README.md) does not have any APIs that allow to patch annotations. I could always delete and recreate the service, but I'd like to patch it.

This is a simple MCVE if someone wants. A test service YAML

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  annotations:
    description: my test service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```

and the Python code I'm using

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException

config.load_kube_config()

coreV1 = client.CoreV1Api()
appsV1 = client.AppsV1Api()

try:
    resp = coreV1.read_namespaced_service("my-service", "default")
    del resp.metadata.annotations["description"]
    patch = coreV1.patch_namespaced_service("my-service", "default", body=resp)
    print(patch)

except ApiException as e:
     print(str(e))
```

Comment: I regret that GitHub is so dumb that I cannot link to the actual line, and it does not appear the kubernetes-client has a GitHub Pages or readthedocs, but search [CoreV1Api.md](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-client/python/v12.0.1/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md) for `V1Service patch_namespaced_service`, which [is how they patch in their example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/v12.0.1/examples/node_labels.py#L39)

Comment: @mdaniel: I actually tried patch_namespace_service, which doesn't seem to work for my specific case of removing annotations. The bigger context is I'm doing some integration test runs on my cluster. What I usually do is take a backup of my service config, do my required patching (in this case remove the annotations) and call the patch API. But for this use case (removing annotations) it is not working

Comment: Then you will need to include your code and error message on a site for programming questions

Comment: @mdaniel: I've updated an MCVE, you can revert your close and down vote now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An annotation is part of the overall metadata for a resource. The API functions are related to patching the resource, not the annotation specifically.

The Kubernetes API documents a [PATCH to a Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#patch-service-v1-core) which equates to `patch_namespaced_service` in the [python API](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/README.md).
The JSON required to delete an annotation is:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "annotations": {
      "your/thing": null
    }
  }
}
```

Python will serialise `None` to `null`

```py
coreV1.patch_namespaced_service("my-service", "default", body={
  "metadata":{"annotations":{"description": None}}
})
```

For any operation, the cli can output the REST calls and "Request Body" if you increase the log level verbosity with `kubectl -v8`:

```
I1112 05:34:08.910667   10552 request.go:1097] Request Body: {"metadata":{"annotations":{"your/thing":null}}}
I1112 05:34:08.910771   10552 round_trippers.go:420] PATCH https://k8s:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/kubernetes?fieldManager=kubectl-annotate
```

Comment: Thanks Mat, but unfortunately patch_namespaced_service is not working to remove annotations (see my MCVE) or may be I'm doing wrong

Comment: Doing `v1.patch_namespaced_service("my-service", "default", body={"metadata":{"annotations":{"description": None}}})` works fine. Let me know if that is right

Comment: Yeah that looks correct... `>>> json.dumps({"a":None}) '{"a": null}'`